# AngularJS: Change encoding of HTML string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, character-encoding

I have an email attachment in HTML format and I'd like to inject it into Angular page. I tried this:

```
$scope.email = $sce.trustAsHtml(email);
```

and

```
<div ng-bind-html="email"></div>
```

and it indeed does display HTML, but some characters are messed up like you can see here (don't mind the pixelated text, I had to protect peoples privacy :)):
[image]

I thought that using **iframe** would help, but result is same:

```
<iframe srcdoc="{{email}}"></iframe>
```

Therefore I assume that I need to **programatically change encoding** of that email (email variable). Is there a way how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once and after spending hours on it, this is the best solution I came up with :) :

I first included the html into my page by using the ng-include:

```
    <ng-include src="'partials/hello.html'" render-html></ng-include>
```

I had the following encoded html in my hello.html partial:

```
&lt;div&gt; hello &lt;/div&gt;
```

The ng-include correctly decoded my html and put it on the screen as text

```
<div> hello </div>
```

Finally, I implemented my directive render-html as follows:

```
myApp.directive('renderHtml',
    function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.html($(element).text());
            }
        };
});
```

With the replacement, my html was correctly processed and rendered onto the screen to only display 'hello' in a div tag.

```
hello
```